# Android App options onkeydown

Tags: android, keyevent

See that button in the right bottom corner with the red cercle around it. Sorry for the size!
I would like to know if there is an KeyEvent for this key and how is the key called.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the soft menu button. You can intercept onKeyPressed of your activity. the KeyEvent is KEYCODE_MENU.

That said... Some people call these three dots in the soft button bar of the galaxy nexus the "menu button of shame". The menu itself is discouraged to use and the elements hidden behind it should be made available through the normal ui.